# Send bcrypt hash as parameter

Tags: url, parameters, bcrypt

I want to send a bcrypt hash with random hash as a URL parameter. For example

```
hash=$2y$10$SWNoIGJpbiBkYXMgU2Fsd.t/I3wS/nUqo5eRQp8b7oakL/kQlZ5da
```

So my questions are:

Is this a good idea or should I remove the salt from the hash? How can I do this? Is the first dot every time the delimiter?

Comment: Or should I use md5(<bcrypt hash>)?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be putting someone BCrypt'd password out on the wire. Even though BCrypt is hard to brute-force; it's better to not make it *easier* for someone to get ahold of it.

I suggest, as user33888366 did, that if you need a kind of security token, use the HMAC of values in the url.

Read [Life in a post-database world: using crypto to avoid DB writes](https://neosmart.net/blog/2015/using-hmac-signatures-to-avoid-database-writes/) for examples of using crypto to trust your urls.

## Short version

```
http://myapp.com/resetPassword?userId=johnnysmith&expirationTime=1356156000&token=%SECURITYHASH%
```

where `%SecurityHash%` is the HMAC hash of:

- userId
- reset expiration time
- bcrypt hash

When the URL comes it, parse it:

```
userId=johnnysmith&expirationTime=1356156000&token=%SECURITYHASH%
       ^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

and recalculate the HMAC of:

- johnnysmith
- 1356156000
- johnnysmith's bcrypt hash

if it matches the passed security token, you know you have a valid request.